# Ember cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We just installed an error-tracker for our Ember-application, and the only error that is reported is `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`. The code that cause this error is within a component, and looks like this:

```
this.set('interval', setInterval(() => {
  const current = this.get('counter') - 1;
  this.set('counter', current);
  this.$().find('.countdown-number').text(current); // <- error here
}, 1000));
```

I don't understand how this can happen. How can `$()` be undefined, since it's a part of the ember framework?

According to the error-tracker, it happens for a bunch of different browsers, latest Chrome for example. I however can't reproduce the error in any browser.

I know this isn't the "ember way" of updating a text in a div, but I would prefer to not have to rebuild a lot, I just want to fix the bug with as little changes as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$()` will be undefined if component is destroyed or didn't render properly. Make sure you call `this.$()` only when component is in DOM and on `willDestroyElement` you remove all events  that could access `this.$()`.

Comment: Ahh, that actually makes a lot of sense! Updated the code in the question above, and as you can see it's an interval that probably keeps going even after the component is destroyed. Adding `clearInterval` to `willDestroyElement` might be a solution, i'll try it out.

Comment: Definitely this should fix things. You have reference stored as `interval` so it should be quick fix. :)

Comment: It works perfectly, not a single error for 4 hours now, while we previously had several every minute. Thanks! :)

Comment: Very happy to hear! :)